# Three dimensional Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have a function
$$
\operatorname{g}\left(r\right) =
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
{\displaystyle 0} & \mbox{if} &
{\displaystyle r < \rho}
\\
{\displaystyle 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-kr}} &&
\mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$
And I have a question that asks: What is the value of $S(\vec{k}) = \int d^3 r [g(\vec{r})-1] e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}\ ?$.

The question said it was a tri-dimensional fourier transform, so I checked on internet what is that and a found that for a tri-dimensional transform

$f(\vec{x}) = \int d^3   k \space \space \mathscr{F}(k) e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} /(2 \pi)^3$

So I assumed that I only need to inverse transform $[g(r)-1]$ and multiply by $1/(2\pi)^3$

Is that right? Cause I got a non-infinity value for $S$, but I had to assume that $r>0$, and the value of $S$ is one-dimensional and only depends of the absolute value of the vector.

Comment: What's ${\large\rho}$ $?$.

Comment: a arbitrary constant

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\operatorname{g}\left(r\right) =}
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
{\displaystyle 0} & \mbox{if} &
{\displaystyle r < \rho}
\\
{\displaystyle 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-kr}} &&
\mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$

---

\begin{align}
\on{S}\pars{\vec{k}} & \equiv
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}
\bracks{\on{g}\pars{r} - 1}\expo{\ic\vec{k}\,{\large\cdot}\,\vec{r}}\dd^{3}\vec{r}}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\on{g}\pars{r} - 1}\
\underbrace{\pars{\int_{\Omega_{\,\vec{\!r}}}
\expo{\ic\vec{k}\,{\large\cdot}\,\vec{r}}\,{\dd\Omega_{\,\vec{r}} \over 4\pi}}}
_{\ds{\sin\pars{kr} \over kr}}
4\pi r^{2}\,\dd r
\\[5mm] & =
{4\pi \over k^{3}}\left[%
\int_{0}^{k\rho}\pars{-1}
\sin\pars{\theta}\,\theta\,\dd\theta\right.
\\[2mm] & \phantom{{4\pi \over k^{3}}\left[\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\right.}
\left. + \int_{k\rho}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic\theta}
\sin\pars{\theta}\,\theta\,\dd\theta\right]
\end{align}

---

The $\ds{\underline{\mbox{first}}}$ integral is equal to $\ds{\quad k\rho\cos\pars{k\rho} - \sin\pars{k\rho}\quad}$ while the
$\ds{\underline{\mbox{second}}}$ one
$\ds{\color{red}{\tt diverges}}$.